# Store an array or a list of objects in Redis v. 5.0 via NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

Is it not possible to store an array of objects or a list of objects via Redis 5.0?

I can only make it work - if I first convert the array/list to JSON-format like this:

```
redis.set('persons', JSON.stringify(array_of_persons)
const persons = JSON.parse(await redis.get('persons'));
```

OR

```
redis.hset('my_list', 'persons', JSON.stringify(array_of_persons));
const persons = JSON.parse(await redis.hget('my_list', 'persons'));
```

But there is a lot of overhead to continuously stringify/parse big collections in javascript when I need to add/update/remove objects from the collections - so how do I performance optimize this code - if it can't be done in a more "native" way in Redis v. 5.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put them in a List in Redis instead of a String. Try:

```
redis.lpush('persons', ...array_of_persons)
```

For the full complement of List commands, check out: https://redis.io/commands#list

Comment: I simply can't remember the details anymore - about this issue... but back then I apparently couldn't get anything to work out well ... but this seems pretty easy :) Also crazy it took someone  months to come up with an answer to my question :D

Comment: I just dropped into StackOverflow, since it has been a while, and this question was unanswered. So I answered it. Didn't even look at the date. Hopefully it helps someone down the road!